# can't re-render child component reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Good day. I can't rerender my child component when state changed.

```
export default class Featured extends React.Component {

constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    result: []
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:'JSONP',
    beforeSend: function (request){
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", Config.key);
    },
    url: "myUrl",
    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({
        result: data.users
      });
      console.log(this.state.result);//here i got my Array
    }.bind(this)
  });
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  this.serverRequest.abort();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div class="">
      <div class="row">
        <Card data={this.state.result} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

I changed state when ajax request success and i have no idea how to rerender my component . Here is some code of

```
export default class extends React.Component {

render() {
  console.log(this.props.data);
  return (
    <div class="flex-container">
      { 
        this.props.data.map(function(item, index) {
          return <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12" key={item._id}>
```

What did i miss? Here is console screen 
http://prntscr.com/ap24x5

Comment: export default class extends React.Component {... you have to name it, you forgot that part

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: fixed by adding dataType:'JSONP', async: false to ajax request and forEach instead of map

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect couple of things I can spot right away:

- you cant use class in the render function, you must use className
- your second component has incorrect incorrect syntax, you need to call it something:

  `export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {`

> Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as class and for are discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components expect DOM property names like className and htmlFor, respectively.

Comment: i can use class instead of className (thx to react-html-attrs plugin)

Comment: and the other issue...? not naming the class?